# Auto Generate Text Yes Or No Sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any sql query to generate a column which is by interval.

See image for Sample:

[image: Sample]

Comment: What's your dbms?What have you ever try?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We are here to help you not do your work for you. Please show us what you have tried so far so we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's no ID in the table, then you could do a modulus check on a ROW_NUMBER.
If your database supports the window functions anyway.

```
select 
 animal,
 (case 
  when (row_number() over (order by animal) % 2) = 1 then 'Yes' 
  else 'No' 
  end) as AutoGenerateValue
from animals
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select animal, DECODE(MOD(rownum,2), 0,'NO', 'YES') from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @table TABLE ( Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) ,Animal VARCHAR(20))


INSERT into @table(Animal)
Select 'Fox'
Union
Select 'Dog'
Union
Select 'Fish'
Union
Select 'Bear'

Select [Animal] ,Case When ID%2 <>0 Then 'Yes' else 'No'  END [AutoGenerateValue] FRom @table
```

[image]